# How can we run the equivalent of the query of "select * from info where Name='$name' && Password='$pass'"; in symfony framework?

Tags: symfony-2.8

there is some problem in symfony framwork ,please solution anybody and help me.

```
Error is=
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\Routing\Route::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony is a framework, with which Doctrine is often associated. Since you are interested in selecting a database record from the info table by Name and Password, you will need to create a Doctrine entity class and a repository:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine/create-entity

and then you will be able to select records using a filter.

Your second problem is about routing. You will need to properly set up your application.